# How to import views from one django views.py to another

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django. I have 2 functions in my app, one for `cats`, and another for `dogs` (as an example). I have the following folder structure:

```
/myproject/templates <-- dogs.html, cats.html
/myproject/dogs/ <-- views.py, models.py etc
/myproject/cats/ <-- views.py, models.py etc
```

Now both `cats` and `dogs` have shared views, etc, but currently I am just repeating these in each `views.py` file. Is there a way to "import" views and definitions from one view to another quickly?

This would save me cut and pasting a lot of the work.

What are the dangers of this? E.g. could conflicts arise? etc.

Comment: Your question is clear but the problem youre trying fo solve is not. If you provide more exact details of your project, we can provide a more useful response

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can use [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and you should use [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) in this case

```
import Animal

class Dog(Animal):
    ....
    pass

class Cat(Animal):
    ....
    pass
```

You must change your urls.py as well

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from dogs.views import Dog
from cats.views import Cat

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dog/', Dog.as_view()),
    url(r'^dog/', Cat.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want a view to inherit all properties of multiple other views?

Comment: you can't inherit another view with FBV (Function Based Views) in Django

Comment: here is the good explanation why to use CBV http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788181/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to have the URLs for cats and dogs point to the same views:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'catsanddogs.views',
    url(r'^(?P<kind>dog|cat)/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'details'),
)
```

And then in `catsanddogs.views`:

```
def details(request, kind, id):
    if kind == "dog":
        ... whatever is specific to dogs ...
    elif kind == "cat":
        ... whatever is specific to cats ...
    else:
        raise ValueError("...")

    ... whatever applies to both ...
    return HttpResponse(...)
```