# Should small specific views be implemented with Function Based views or CBVs?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an app in Django and would like to know what is the correct way to implement some small views that need to implement some specific function. I'm still a beginner and I've been using CBVs from the start but I'm not sure if I should use FBVs for this.

I now need to implement some specific functions when integrating Stripe, for example, to reactive a canceled subscription or to upgrade a subscription and was wondering if I should use FBVs for this?
If not, should I for example use the `POST` of

```
class SubscriptionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request): 
        # Make a new subscription...
```

that I use to create a subscription and just check if the user is trying to reactive/upgrade with a parameter or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56679298/11780428) if you are indecisive on what type of method to use.

But generally some of the advantages of using CBVs on my experience are:

1. They can be easily extended
2. Code re usability
3. Remove branching through the use of class methods, hence clean code.