# Why must I use Function-based views if there is Class-based?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

**From the Django Documentation**

> In the beginning there was only the view function contract, Django
> passed your function an HttpRequest and expected back an HttpResponse.
> This was the extent of what Django provided. Early on it was
> recognized that there were common idioms and patterns found in view
> development. Function-based generic views were introduced to abstract
> these patterns and ease view development for the common cases. The
> problem with function-based generic views is that while they covered
> the simple cases well, there was no way to extend or customize them
> beyond some configuration options, limiting their usefulness in many
> real-world applications. Class-based generic views were created with
> the same objective as function-based generic views, to make view
> development easier. However, the way the solution is implemented,
> through the use of mixins, provides a toolkit that results in
> class-based generic views being more extensible and flexible than
> their function-based counterparts.strong text

Comment: You don't......

Comment: I want to find the best cases using it but I can't.

Comment: @JoraKaryan: class-based views are usually a good idea when the task you have to implement is a standard one: for example listing items of a *single* model. Whereas function-based views are often used if the logic is "complicated" and does not fit any of the class-based views: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56679298/67579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the answers listed above, we can use function based view when there is a single HTTP Method (GET/POST/PATCH etc) against a particular URL. In this case we don't need as_view() to map to correct handler methods as there is only one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Class-based views in Django is excellent. They are very abstract and sort of handle many things on their own. They can also be altered to fit what you want to implement, but function-based views are very explicit, and often more straightforward if you're going to implement something different or complicated stuff. [This may show you why some people like to use function-based  views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKzStOGIc4A)