# When to use Class based view and Function based view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

As I am learning Django, but I'm little bit confused about the **class based view** and **function based view**. Can you explain **when to use them** and what are the differences between them?

Comment: This has been well answered in this [Stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788181/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views) and [Django Forums](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/using-class-based-or-function-based-views/2598)